# centrar elemento en angular

Tags: html, angular, aplicación-web

Quiero colocar en el centro este recueadro, pero no me deja.
(no debo ocupar el css para este caso), tampoco puedo centrar la imagen que tengo arriba del título y el texto pequeño que esta debajo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui esta el código del html

```
    <div class="body"fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center" >
     <mat-card>
        <img src="../../assets/images/Logo.png" alt="Logo" width="100">
        <mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-title>
                <span>Ingresar al sistema</span>
                <h5>Sigue tu Proyecto</h5>
            </mat-card-title>
        </mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-content fxLayout="column">
            <mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
                <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
                <input matInput [(ngModel)]="currentUser.emailAddress" required>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
                <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
                <input matInput type="password"  [(ngModel)]="currentUser.password" required>
            </mat-form-field>
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions fxLayoutAlign="center">
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="login()">Ingresar</button>
        </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres centrar el div en la pantalla Tenes que asegurarte que el body de tu web tenga el 100% del height y también el contenedor padre donde Tenes esa card.

Answer (score 1):

No veo el cierre de la etiqueta `</div>`, ese puede ser el problema;

- Utiliza `fxLayoutAlign="center center">` Ese es el problema.

Comment: si tenia la finalización del div, tambien le cambie a center center, pero aun así no funciona